# Intuition between the equivalence between Cech and Singular Cohomology?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

We know that, under suitable assumptions, the Cech Cohomology of a topological space is isomorphic to the singular cohomology. The proof seems to be mostly algebraic.

I am wondering: is there a geometric way of seeing this correspondence? Possibly could we picture it in some way, just like what we do when defining singular homology?

Comment: The fact that such an isomorphism fails in general, indicates that there is no intuitive proof of this. I suggest, you work on understanding the proof as it is, I am unaware of any easy arguments.

Answer (score 3):

I have not checked any of the details of the argument below, but I can try to expand if something looks wrong or dubious.

If a space has a *good* cover: a locally finite cover so that all finite intersections are either empty or contractible, then the space is homotopy equivalent to the nerve of this cover. This is sometimes called the nerve lemma. If you just care about singular cohomology, the isomorphism between the (simplicial) cohomology of the nerve and the singular cohomology of the space follows from contractible spaces being (singular) acyclic and the Mayer-Vietoris property for singular cohomology.

Čech cohomology is the limit (over refinement of covers) of the cohomology of the nerve of the cover. So if the space is topologically nice enough that there is a cofinal set of good covers then can compute the limit along good covers which by above produces singular cohomology.